# Hasekll choice of matrix using replicate

Tags: haskell, grid

I am trying to solve a problem that I don't know how to approach: how would you use `replicate` to define a matrix `choice :: Matrix [Int]` that contains `[1 .. 9]` in every cell?

Comment: Please provide some more context. Your question is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that you want a 9-by-9 grid with a list in each entry, and that the definition of `Matrix` looks like the following:

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]
```

Now, the function `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` takes an `Int` and some type `a`, repeating it that many times.

Thus something we can try first is: how do we create a list with `[1..9]` in every element?

```
Prelude> replicate 9 [1..9]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

The output is edited slightly to display each element in its own row, but this is effectively a single row in the matrix, isn't it? Why don't we just repeat it 9 more times?

```
Prelude> replicate 9 $ replicate 9 [1..9]
[[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
,[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]]
```